# Setting ANDROID_NDK_PLATFORM in Ubuntu

Tags: qt, android-studio, pyqtdeploy

What is `ANDROID_NDK_PLATFORM` env variable and how do we choose the value for it for 
 building with Qt Creator in `ubuntu`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to set any environment variables. Just install Android Studio, have it download the SDKs you want, let it also install the NDK. After that, open Qt Creator, and set up the paths in the "Devices" section of the settings.

In my case, I installed Android Studio into my home directory into `/home/realnc/opt/android-studio`, and it installed the SDK and NDK into `/home/realnc/opt/Android`. So I use the following paths in Creator:

[image: Qt Creator Android Settings]